# Add text inside the switch using material ui

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI's Switch component and I want to add text inside it. I want something like in the image below.

[image]

Here's my code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';

export default function Switches() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkedA: true,
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Switch
        checked={state.checkedA}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="checkedA"
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'secondary checkbox' }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I already searched for the answer and found [How to add text inside a Switch Component in Material-UI React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61723479/how-to-add-text-inside-a-switch-component-in-material-ui-react) and [Add text to Switch formcontrol and change it in toggle using material ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128013/add-text-to-switch-formcontrol-and-change-it-in-toggle-using-material-ui) . Both of them were not helpful for me.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible as of version 4.11.0. The examples put the labels outside the switch component. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20188

Comment: Take a look here (Switch I): https://mui-treasury.com/styles/switch/

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve this by adding pseudo-elements `:after` and `:before` to `Switch`'s `track` inner element with text inside them. Add `content` property to these pseudo-elements with the desired text and place them using absolute positioning.

*To override Material-UI components style you can use `makeStyles` hook generator.
To reach component's inner elements you can use prop `classes` or regular global class names like `.MuiSwitch-track`. See https://material-ui.com/customization/components/*

Please check my codesandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-euler-98tqo?file=/src/App.js